# How to aggregate different metrics by host, keeping them separate by node

Tags: graphite

So I have an application, deployed on many hosts, reporting to graphite. Metrics will follow this scheme:

```
domain.<hostname>.metricspath.<metricName>.mean
```

I would like to have them averaged per host name, but sill show up as different metricName. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [averageSeriesWithWildcards function](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.averageSeriesWithWildcards):

> `averageSeriesWithWildcards(seriesList, *position)`
>
> Call averageSeries after inserting wildcards at the given position(s).
>
> Example:
>
> `&target=averageSeriesWithWildcards(host.cpu-[0-7].cpu-{user,system}.value, 1)`
>
> This would be the equivalent of
> `target=averageSeries(host.*.cpu-user.value)&target=averageSeries(host.*.cpu-system.value)`

In your case you can use `averageSeriesWithWildcards(domain.*.metricspath.*.mean, 1)`.